# How set element align half all form in Delphi 7?

Tags: delphi, alignment, dbgrid

Hello I create a form and put into the form two DBGrid. And set align Left to right of both. When i run the program and maximized window DBGrid width not changing. what i need to change width both of DBGrid to 50% of window?

Comment: I want do it like Total Commander two ement width by 50% width

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the left control (`Control1`, say) to `alLeft` and the right control (`Control2`, say) to `alClient`. Then create a `OnResize` handler on the parent form:

```
procedure TForm1.FormResize(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Control1.Width := ClientWidth div 2;
end;
```